# Произведение элементов массива Java

Tags: java, массивы

Почему мой код не работает?

Нужно создать массив, заполнить случайными числами от 1 до 10 и найти произведение всех этих чисел.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = new int[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 11);
    }
    long p = array[0] * array[1] * array[2] * array[3] * array[4] * array[5] * array[6] * array[7] * array[8] * array[9];
    System.out.println(p);
}
```

Comment: "мой код не работает" - что это значит?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 10 out of bounds for length 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int p = 0; // !!! Не торопитесь. Подумайте.
...
  p = p * array[i];
```

---

Вы доводите счетчик внешего цикла `i` до `array.length` во внутреннем цикле. Зачем тут вложенные циклы?

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int[] array = new int[10];
  int p = 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
    p = p * array[i];
  }
  System.out.println(p);
}
```

Comment: убрал второй цикл, все ровно не понимаю что-то как перемножить каждый элемент и вывести общее число

Comment: @gunniq Возьмите листок бумаги и выполните на нем Ваш код шаг за шагом.

Comment: p = array[0] * 2 + array[1] * 2 + array[3] * 2;
                System.out.println(p);

Comment: а вот так правильно будет? правда не совсем красиво

Comment: What the fuck is this? Это что, *произведение* элементов массива?

Comment: Ой, это я спешу) p=array[0] * array[1] * array[3].... , так будет правильно?

Comment: @gunniq Результат получается правильный?

Comment: Думаю скорее да, чем нет.  И я нашел еще проблему - массив идет от 0 до 10, а не от 1 до 10, и если попадается 0 то и общий результат получается 0.

Comment: @gunniq Возьмите листок бумаги и выполните на нем Ваш код шаг за шагом.

Comment: я нашел решение, обновил шапку, посмотрите пожалуйста. У меня все работает и выдает нужное значение, но можно ли как то сделать короче?

Comment: @gunniq Вам что, не виден код в ответе?

Comment: Он не работает так как нужно, выдает кучу чисел с новой строчки.  а мой выводит одно число.

Comment: @gunniq Вы неаккуратно скопировали к себе мой код.

Comment: блин и правда, это я невнимательный :( Спасибо за терпение